# codeigniter messaging app inbox database fetching issue

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am building a private messaging app for my website using codeigniter. Everything works but i have a major problem with fetching inbox conversations. When USER A sends message to USER B. User B is able to receive the message; it fetches the message detail and the user a details including avatar and username , but when USER C sends USER B a message too. Every message (including user A's details like Avatar and name (message and subject doesnt  though))  changes to User C making them the sender of the original message. I am not sure whats wrong. Below is my database structure and my codes.

```
  conversation table
----------------------------------------------------
conversation_id |  conversation_subject
____________________________________________________
18              | hello there.
19              | Chelsea is winning tomorrow
___________________________________________________

conversations members table 

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
conversation_id |  user_id | conversation_last_view | conversation_deleted 
___________________________________________________________________________
18              | 1        | 0                      | 0
18              | 11       | 0                      | 0
19              | 1        | 0                      | 0
19              | 13       | 0                      | 0
___________________________________________________________________________

conversations messages 

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
message_id      |conversation_id        |  user_id |  message_date        | message_text
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
18              | 1                     | 1        | 2016-05-03 20:06:53  |  I just want you to know that , you shaa 
18              | 11                    | 13       | 2016-05-03 20:23:53  |  hello guy
_______________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

controller =

```
    public function inbox()   {   

                          $user['user'] = $this->data;

                          // store's logged in user's id

                          $user_id = $user['user'][0]->id;             


                 $taxi['conversation'] = $this->conversation_model->fetch_messages($user_id);


                 if (!empty($taxi['conversation'])) {    

                     $conversation_id =  $taxi['conversation'] [0]['conversation_id'];



                       $conversation['inbox'] = $this->conversation_model->fetch_inbox($conversation_id,$user_id);

                     //fetches member of the conversation

                      $member_id =  $taxi2['inbox'] [0]-> user_id;


 // Fetching message member that will later appear as the sender on the inbox page.

                    $message_member['sender'] = $this->conversation_model->fetch_member($member_id);


                      // merge all the data
                    $inbox = array_merge($user,$conversation,$message_member);

                        $this->load->view('template/inbox',$inbox);

                 }
                 else {



                        $this->load->view('template/no_message');


                 }

                }
```

MODEL

```
     public function fetch_member($member_id) 

            {    


              $q = $this->db->get_where('gamers', array('id' => $member_id));



              if ($q->num_rows > 0) {



                return $q->result();

              }

              return false;


                    } 

     public function fetch_inbox($conversation_id,$sender_id) 

            {    



            $query = $this->db->query( "select conversations_members.conversation_id,conversations_members.user_id,conversations_members.conversation_last_view,\n"
        . "conversations_members.conversation_deleted,conversations_messages.message_id,conversations_messages.message_date,conversations_messages.message_text\n"
        . "\n"
        . "from conversations_members\n"
        . "\n"
        . "\n"
        . "inner join conversations on conversations_members.conversation_id = conversations.conversation_id 
           inner join conversations_messages on conversations.conversation_id = conversations_members.conversation_id 
           where conversations.conversation_id = $conversation_id and conversations_members.conversation_deleted = 0 and conversations_members.user_id <> $sender_id" );


              $results= $query->result();

                 return $results;


                    }   

 public function fetch_messages($sender_id) 

        {    


         $this->db->select('conversations.conversation_id,conversations.conversation_subject,conversations_messages.message_text');
         $this->db->select_max('conversations_messages.message_date', 'conversation_last_reply');
         $this->db->select_max('conversations_messages.message_date > conversations_members.conversation_last_view', 'conversation_unread');
         $this->db->from('conversations');
         $this->db->join('conversations_messages','conversations.conversation_id=conversations_messages.conversation_id','left');
         $this->db->join('conversations_members','conversations.conversation_id= conversations_members.conversation_id','inner');
         $this->db->where('conversations_members.user_id',$sender_id);
         $this->db->where('conversations_members.conversation_deleted','0');
         $this->db->group_by('conversations.conversation_id');
         $this->db->order_by('conversation_last_reply', 'desc');
         // Get the results from db
         $query = $this->db->get();
         // Result array contains the records selected
         $result_array = $query->result_array();

         return $result_array;



                }
```

UPDATE  :  i think the problems comes from this part

```
            $taxi['conversation'] = $this->conversation_model->fetch_messages($user_id);


             if (!empty($taxi['conversation'])) {    

                 $conversation_id =  $taxi['conversation'] [0]['conversation_id'];
```

it returns an array of conversation details like messages , text and conversation member's ids. like below

```
Array ( [conversation] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [conversation_id] => 25 [conversation_subject] => helloooooooo guy [message_text] => hello [conversation_last_reply] => 2016-05-08 02:59:06 [conversation_unread] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [conversation_id] => 23 [conversation_subject] => this is new [message_text] => helllo [conversation_last_reply] => 2016-05-03 20:06:53 [conversation_unread] => 1 ) ) )
```

I am suppose to pick each and every conversation_id from the arrays. But imagine if there's like 400 conversations to display . how do i fetch all the conversation_id's from the array and then store them into another array so i can use it to fetch each conversation member from the 400 messages ? Sounds a bit impossible to me. Is there another way i can make this simple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved my problem by adding columns like from_user_avatar  and to_user_avatar to the message table .. i did the same with the username etc  and it worked like a charm.